# Anyone else having problems with the intuit.ipp.anywhere.logout call

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

During the sign out process, I'm calling intuit.ipp.anywhere.logout and passing it a callback function. The callback function is processed correctly; however, it does not sign out of the app center. Anyone else having similar problems?

```
logout: function (callback) {
    intuit.ipp.jQuery.ajax({
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ajax' of undefined (repeated 2 times)
                url: "https://" + intuit.ipp.anywhere.serviceHost + "/Account/LogoutJSONP?callback=?",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                complete: function () {
                    callback();
                    //intuit.ipp.anywhere.view.popup.hide();
                }
            });
    //intuit.ipp.anywhere.view.logout.render(callback);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you including https://js.appcenter.intuit.com/Content/IA/intuit.ipp.anywhere.js?  I'm not sure of the origin of"uncaught TypeError..."

This simple test HTML page works fine: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19213950/logout.html
Once you're logged into AppCenter, click on the logout link on this test HTML and you should see your AppCenter session invalidated.